# Getting the "border Y-values" in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is pretty simple, but yet I struggle to find an answer. Brief context, I have a sprite that moves accross the Y-axis according to microphone input. Beforehand, I prompted the user to record their lowest and highest note, calculated the frequency of these two notes and am using it as a reference for positioning the sprite on the Y-axis.

Let's say the lowest note is 100 Hz and the highest one 400 Hz. So if the player makes a tone of 100 Hz, the sprite should move down to the bottom of the Y-axis. To move back to the center (Y-position 0), the player would have to make a tone of 250 Hz (midpoint between 100 and 400).

So we know that for that player, 250 Hz equals to Y-position 0. But I need to know the Y-position equivalents of the lowest note (bottom edge) and highest note (top edge). When I move the sprite manually to the top edge and look at the Y-value in the inspector, it's apparently 4.58. But I'm not sure if hard-coding 4.58 would scale well across different screen-sized devices.
Screenshot here: https://i.ibb.co/pjrkSNV/Capture.png

I ideally want to have a method called FrequencyToY(float frequency) that converts a frequency value to the corresponding Y-value on the axis. I saved the lowest and highest frequency values in PlayerPrefs. Important note about the sprite movement, I don't want gravity. The bird should just smoothly move to the corresponding Y-position every time the player produces a tone, and stay in place otherwise.

This is my current script attached to my sprite:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audioPlayer;
    public AudioMixer masterMixer;
    private float[] _spectrum;
    private float _fSample;

    private Transform playerTransform;

    void Start()
    {
        playerTransform = transform;

        //Code for microphone loop
        masterMixer.SetFloat("masterVolume", -80f);
        _spectrum = new float[AudioAnalyzer.QSamples];
        _fSample = AudioSettings.outputSampleRate;
        audioPlayer.clip = Microphone.Start("", true, 10, 44100);
        audioPlayer.loop = true;
        while(!(Microphone.GetPosition("") > 0)) { }
        audioPlayer.Play();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Calculate frequency of currently detected tones
        audioPlayer.GetSpectrumData(_spectrum, 0, FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris);
        float pitchVal = AudioAnalyzer.calculateFrequency(ref _spectrum, _fSample);
        if(pitchVal != 0)
        {
            if (pitchVal < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("lowestFrequency"))
                pitchVal = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("lowestFrequency");
            else if (pitchVal < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highestFrequency"))
                pitchVal = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highestFrequency");

            //This is how I'd like to call the function
            //But if someone could change this and make the sprite actually 
            //"move" to that point instead of just popping there it would be awesome!
            transform.position = new Vector2(0, FrequencyToY(pitchVal));
        }
    }

    //Converts frequency to position on Y-axis
    public float FrequencyToY(float frequency)
    {
        float x = 0;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the range of your Y coordinates that you want to use (say, 0 -> 100) and then scale the pitch you're given against their scale (so what % on 0 - 100 of their scale) and then use that % as a point on Y.

Thus, if they give you a note that's exactly in the middle of their scale (50%) and your Y coordinates in game range from 0-10, you want to put them at 5.

Comment: That's a good idea, but the main problem still remains unsolved. You said "IF your Y coordinates in game range from 0-10", that's the point, I do NOT know the range of my Y coordinates and want a solution that would work accross all devices

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html @M.Benamar